Understanding how initialization with initializer list works in C
Here are two possible ways to initialize an array, using initializer list:
int arr[2] = {1, 2};

and assigning the values to the array one by one:
int arr[2];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

Compiling them using gcc 13.2 (with the -O0 optimization flag) on Godbolt results in exactly the same assembly code:
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret

However, when I try this with variable-length arrays (VLAs), the two methods are not only not equivalent, but the second also gives an error:
size_t n = 2;
int arr[n];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;  // OK

size_t n = 2;
int arr[n] = {1, 2};  // EROR

What is the fundamental difference between these two ways of initialization? Why exactly does using initializer list fail with VLAs?

The language doesn't allow providing an initialization list with VLA, because it can't tell at compile time whether there are enough or too many initializers.

But why can it do so in the first example? What if at runtime n becomes 1, but we have assigned arr[0] and arr[1] at compile time? Shouldn't be allowed either.

The first example isn't a VLA. It knows the size of the array, it can compare that to the number of initializers.

You're getting the same generated code because of an optimization that detects that they're the same. It might be different for int arr[10] because then it has to add zeroes for elements 2-9 when you use an initialization list.

By first example I mean at the bottom, i.e. size_t n = 2;, int arr[n]; It isn't a VLA?

Of course that's a VLA. That's why you're not allowed to use an initialization list, you have to assign to elements normally.

Why would you want to provide an initialization list when you don't know how many elements there will be until the program runs? VLA is normally used when you get the size dynamically.

Well, it would be handy to be able to do arr[n] = {1, 2} to initialize just the first two values, even if n > 2 (the rest of the array elements would be garbage values), just like using arr[0] = 1 and arr[1] = 2.

Unfortunately, the language designers prohibited this when they added VLA. Your intended use case is very unusual.

So to use initializer list, the list must have the same number of elements as the size of the array, by design. We can't do int arr[2] = {1,2,3};, even though we are allowed (but not advised) to do int arr[2]; and then arr[0] = 1;, arr[1] = 2;, arr[2] = 3;.

It doesn't have to have the same number. If it has more items, the excess is ignored. If it has fewer, the rest of the array will be initialized with 0.

When the array has a known size, the compiler can figure out which case it is when compiling. With a VLA, it can't tell until the code executes. The designers decided not to require that kind of run-time check.

Please correct me if I am wrong, in the first VLA example the assignment of values is done at runtime after the array size becomes known (also at runtime), whereas in the second VLA example, we basically are trying to assign values at compile time when the array size is unknown yet.

Essentially. But it can't do it at compile time because the size isn't known.

Of course, your int arr[2]; … arr[2] = 3; example has UB.

The initializer list can have less entries than the number of elements of the array. The remaining elements will be initialized to 0. (Also, I assume you know already about autosizing the array from the initializer, like int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}; initializing an array of length 3?)

Since C2x it's allowed to use empty initilazer {} for VLA, but not an arbitrary one. (btw {} just generates a correspondent memset() call for vla in gcc13 for example)

@Barmar: Re “If it has more items, the excess is ignored”: If the initializer list has more items than the array has elements, it is a constraint violation, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard beyond the fact that a diagnostic message must be issued. C 2018 6.7.9 2: “No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.”

arr[0] = 1; is not initialization but (run-time) assignment. It may or may not have an effect on the generated machine code, but language-wise initialization and assignment are different concepts (and even more so in C++).
VLA cannot be initialized with an initializer list because the C standard simply  forbids it1). But most of the time, doing so wouldn't make much sense: if you know how many items there are, why are you using a VLA and not a fixed-size array?
The obvious work-around is memcpy:
size_t n=5;
int arr[n];
int some_init_list[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
memcpy(arr, some_init_list, sizeof arr);

Or if you will:
memcpy(arr, (int[]){1,2,3,4,5}, sizeof arr);

Partial/zero initialization can be done either by memset on the VLA in advance, or by filling up remaining items in the init list with zeroes before copying it. Also as noted in comments, upcoming C23 will support empty initialization lists int vla[n]={}; to zero-out the VLA.
1) C17 6.7.9 Constrains: "The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type."
